# Problems using Include to show properties value

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I'm learning **ASP.NET core** and having this problem. I have two *Foreign Key* properties, which I want to show in my *GET* method. The model looks like this:

```
[Key]
public int WorkRoomId { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("Room")]
[Required]
public int RoomId { get; set; }
public Room Room { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("ApplicationUser")]
[Required]
public string Id { get; set; }
public virtual ApplicationUser Employee { get; set; }
```

The `ApplicationUser` is `identityUser`, and My *GET* method in Controller is:

```
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<WorkRoom>>> GetWorkRooms()
{
    var workRooms =await _context.WorkRooms
       .Include(i => i.Room)
       .Include(i => i.Employee)
       .ToListAsync();
    return workRooms;
}
```

When i "GET" this,  i received:

```
[
  {
    "workRoomId": 1,
    "roomId": 1,
    "room": {
      "roomId": 1,
      "roomName": "H-103"
    },
    "id": "0dadca05-5133-428c-936b-6b5569e33286",
    "employee": null
  }
]
```

Why the room works normally but the employee doesn't?

Do I need to add something for this to work out?

If I can show "employee" normally, how can I select just some fields from ApplicationUser to show, cause there are many fields I don't need to show? Cause it seems like the select function only show properties from WorkRoom for me to select.

Comment: Try to use `EmployeeId` instead of `Id`, by convention EF Core use this syntax to match the foreign keys.

Comment: Is that the main problem? Cause I'm using ApplicationUser table, when I tried to change to EmployeeId it got the errors. Can you introduce the detail process?

Comment: Can you show the full `WorkRoom` class?

Comment: Ok, my bad, now I understand. Your application user table is defined as `Employee` in your DbSet ?

Comment: It's just the name Employee, cause i dont have any table name like that, I;m using identityUser, in Db it's IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>. and Id is the basic properties of it. or maybe I'm misunderstand sth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your such model, it will create a table with a Foreign Key named `EmployeeId` in database(**You could open your database to check if it is correct or not. Or check the migration file**). But what you think `Id` is the foreign key, so that is why you set the value for `Id` but cannot get the related `ApplicationUser` data.

Change your WorkRoom class like below, then run command `add migration` and `update database` again to update the database:

```
public class WorkRoom
{
    [Key]
    public int WorkRoomId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Room")]
    [Required]
    public int RoomId { get; set; }
    public Room Room { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Employee")]   //change here...
    [Required]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser Employee { get; set; }
}
```

**Update:**

```
var workRooms =  _context.WorkRooms
                        .Include(i => i.Room)
                        .Include(i => i.Employee).Select(i=>new { 
                               Room = i.Room,
                               EmployeeId = i.Employee.Id,
                               i.WorkRoomId
                        }).ToList();
```

Comment: Can I ask how to Select just some specific fields to show in the "employee" cause there 're many fields I don't need it ApplicationUser? I know how to to do it with flat properties but don't know how to do it with foreign key. I'll update the question above.